# ChartJS rotate 90' but keep text straight

Tags: chart.js

New user ChartJs v3.3, I have managed to create multiple radar charts and rotate it 90', the problem I can't seems to fix is the rotation for the ticks(I'm not sure if this is what is call)...
[image: Radar chart with 90' rotation]
As you can see the radar chart has been rotated 90' but the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 are also rotated, in the documentation don't mention anything regarding that part, if this are the "ticks" I have try using the `maxRotation` but did nothing.
This is my current configuration:

```
const _options =   {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
     legend: {
      display: false,
      labels: {
       color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
      }
     },
    },
    scales: {
     r: {
      beginAtZero:true,
      startAngle: 90,
      max:4,
      min:0,
      ticks: {
       stepSize:1,
      // maxRotation: 40
      }
     }
    }
   };
```

The number are in the correct position and the chart itself is rotated correctly just the numbers are not rotated properly.
Like I said I'm a noob using this library(ChartJs).
Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default, looking at the source of chart.js they dont pass any rotation paramater to their text draw function where those labels are drawn: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/ed73dce18bd5a2d523409d1fcaadaf2bcdd1d89c/src/scales/scale.radialLinear.js#L552

So atm the only way to achieve this would be to render empty string using the scale callback and draw then numbers on the canvas yourself with an custom inline plugin